# Modal Closes, but scroll bar doesn't come back

Tags: html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar

I have a Bootstrap 3 modal that will close and return my page to the proper state (which is showing a vertical scroll bar) when I close it with the 'close button' or the 'x' in the top right corner. However when I attempt to have a "select button" in the modal close it after making an ajax call the vertical scroll bar does not return to the page. In the code I have the 'onclick' event calling .modal('hide') as well as having: data-dismiss="modal" on the button itself. The ajax call executes correctly as well. I can't see why this is preventing the scroll bar from reappearing in the same manner as when one of the close buttons is selected.

--Thank you for your insights.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_1timepmt" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="1timepmtLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog admin_modal_dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Some Other Details</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container content-box live-box">
        <h3>Some Heading Here</h3>
        <form id="date_exp" name="date_exp">
            <div class="form-group" id="exp_form">
                <label for="log_start" class="control-label"><small>Date</small></label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" name="exp_date" id="exp_date" data-format="yyyy-mm-dd" >
                <a href="/?object=result_detail&action=exp_date" onclick="priv_ajax.go({
                    url:this.href,
                    div:'web_adm_details',
                    data:priv_forms.capture(document.forms['date_exp'])
                }); return false; $('#modal_1timepmt').modal('hide');" >
                 <button style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"  class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Select</button></a>
            </div>
        </form> 
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to recreate your issue. Bash this Bootply around (http://www.bootply.com/cSgdTf8ER2) and see if you can make the problem appear...

Comment: Thanks for looking Shawn. I added in some generic nav links on the left margin to recreate the existence of a scroll bar before the modal is shown. It closes properly and the scroll bar is still there. I suspect that without the ajax method I'm calling (priv_ajax.go();) it just hits the .modal('hide') and closes fine. Since I haven't written all of the code (or css) for this site, I was just hoping someone might have run into this before. Thanks again...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To help anyone else who may run into this. Upon further inspection of the DOM after the modal closed I noticed that body still had this class applied: ".modal-open".

Removal of this class would bring the page back to normal conditions. The following simple line of code attached to the onclick event solved this issue (although I still haven't figured out the underlying cause).

```
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
```

Comment: thank you! I had an ajax call in rails to close a modal and the page wouldn't scroll. adding this line fixed it for me! For anyone else in a similar situation, I had to do these 3 lines to fully close a modal:

`$('#specific-div').modal('hide');`
`$('.modal-backdrop').remove();`
`$('body').removeClass('modal-open');`

Comment: I'm glad this helped someone. It stumped me for a good while!

Comment: Thanks for this very useful answer which helped me to identify the problem.  However, I really do want to determine the root cause to find out why that class isn't being removed by itself.  The most frustrating part is that I've asked several coworkers to test this and out of 5 people, only 2 people got he 'modal-open' class after closing the modal.  Really incomprehensible.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ++

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to make just new css class for all opened modals. So make CSS class

```
.modal.fade.in {overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;}
```

This will solve the problem for all modals.

PS: I had a problem that after I opened modal from modal and the second modal was too long i could not scroll (because javascript registered `data-dismiss="modal"` so he forgot to remember that I also call `data-toggle="modal"` for another so it took away `class="modal-open"` from the body of the document. In bootstrap CSS style for

```
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I am not so good with javascript, so unfortunately cannot solve this problem somehow nicer in java. :)

Answer (score 0):

May be the modal popup is not closed correctly.

Code to hide modal popup

```
$("#ModalId").modal("hide");
```